# SP13: Document Library (PDF) not opening

Tags: 2013, document-library, css, pdf

I have a document library (all documents are pdf) that came from SP10 to SP13.  In SP10 the documents open without an issue.  In SP13 when I click on "doc type" icon the document will not open.  Through research I found that this is a issue that Microsoft has not fixed in SP13, but I could be wrong.  If I add "title" column the document will open, however, I only want to open the document from the document type.  Can anyone assist me with this issue?  Is there any css I can apply to the document library page?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.  Yes, this is a Microsoft issue that hasn't been fixed in 2013.  So, I found this helpful page that solved the issue for SP2013: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-2013-Clicking-the-icon-in-Type-column-is-highlighting-the-item-instead-of-launching-the-document.aspx.  Thanks for your help SharePoint Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You could also adjust `DocIcon.xml` in `15\TEMPLATE\XML\` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms463701%28v=office.14%29.aspx). This means in particular adding the OpenControl like this:

```
<Mapping Key="pdf" Value="pdficon_small.png" OpenControl="AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments"/>
```

Note, that this requires Acrobat Reader X or higher.